# Ooyala player setembedcode

Tags: html, ooyala

I am trying to implement Ooyala's player in my code and I was told that if I wanted to use buttons to switch the content of the video player then I should use the setEmbedCode function but the examples they have on their site aren't very clear.

What I want to have happen is to simply have a link that when clicked will change the video to a different URL/embed code. I've tried using the 'setQueryStringParameters'

```
document.getElementById('video-player'+pageNum).setQueryStringParameters({embedCode:videoURL})
```

All I get with that is a:

> 'is not a function message.'

```
var url = 'http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?embedCode='+videoURL+'&amp;targetReplaceId=video-player'+pageNum+'';
var tempScript = document.createElement('script');
tempScript.type = 'text/javascript';
tempScript.src = url;
```

When I call this it creates the video player just fine, but I'm not sure how to change the embed code once it's created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this sample code from ooyala site. "SwitchMovie" will play different video with different embedcode.

http://demo.ooyala.com/product-demos/playerScripting-demo.html

```
document.getElementById('player').setQueryStringParameters({embedCode:'8wNTqa-6MkpEB1c7fNGOpoSJytLptmm9',hide:'share,fullscreen'})
```

**UPDATE:**

The following code is working perfect for me. Try it, as I mentioned in my comments below you need to have a callback function if you need to interface with the player.

```all
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Swap Video</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?callback=receiveOoyalaEvent&playerId=player&width=480&height=360&embedCode=llMDQ6rMWxVWbvdxs2yduVEtSrNCJUk1&version=2"></script>
<script>
function receiveOoyalaEvent(playerId, eventName, eventArgs) {
}
</script>
<br><br>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('player').setQueryStringParameters({embedCode:'8wNTqa-6MkpEB1c7fNGOpoSJytLptmm9',hide:'share,fullscreen'})">Switch Movie</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you read my question, I mention that when I try to call that function it says it's not a function.

Comment: did you have the callback function in you player script.? Could you post your complete code including the player script code.?

Comment: What callback function? I can't post all of my code as there's a ton of it but I updated my question with the code that I use to create the video player.

Comment: You are missing the playerid in your script.. `var url = 'http://player.ooyala.com/player.js?embedCode='+videoURL+'&amp;playerId=video-player'+pageNum+'';`. You are not using any callback functions.

Comment: It's right there: playerId=video-pl‌​ayer'+pageNum. Again, it's only when I'm using the setQuery that it doesn't work.

Comment: What you have is 'targetReplaceId=video-player'.. the name has to be playerId not targetReplaceId.

Comment: Ahh, well I added that part to it and it's still saying the exact same thing. setQuery is not a function.

Comment: The replaceId is used to specify a specific location to place the player.